# Как подключиться и добавить пользователей в hmailserver c#?

Tags: c#, .net

Пишу программу для получения и отправки писем , хочу сделать добавление пользователей в hmailserver при помощи c#, как это реализовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1101963/Tips-on-hMailServer-Manipulation-using-Csharp Вот подробно описано добавление,удаление пользователей)